# What is the IAmHappyWhereIAm cookie set by careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cookies

I was just inspecting what cookies are set on StackOverflow (you know, as you do) and one in particular caught my eye:

```
Name             Value        Domain                    Path Expires
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IAmHappyWhereIAm IGotSunshine careers.stackoverflow.com /    2016...
```

What is this whimsically named and valued cookie used for and what is the story behind its name/value?

Comment: This naming scheme is a case for code-review.

Comment: Looking through the [relevant documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZh7nRw6gl8), this seems to be a known bug. Some preliminary questions based on the previous bug report: (1) Is it a cloudy day? (2) Do you have a "girl"?

Comment: @usr At least they follow .NET's rule for naming interfaces...

Comment: @usr there are more : superSecretTrackingCookie and  superSecretTrackingCookie2

Comment: Gotta catch them all, then trade them with your friends !

Comment: Have you tried clapping your hands?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I added this.  When we introduced localization, there used to be a popup for where-to-direct-you to the site we thought you might prefer; it was part of our plan to increase exposure for our translated sites.  That cookie means, don't show me that popup anymore, and it's a cookie because not everyone is logged in for me to store it in preferences.

As for where the name and value came from, IAmHappyWhereIAm seemed appropriate, and IGotSunshine was because I was listening to the song [My Girl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIYAuJ5OZ1Y) when I wrote it.